# not using `new` keyword for contructor prototype method mutates original object

Tags: javascript

Given the following code I would log 2 instances of the Person prototype

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name
}

person = new Person('bob');
person2 = new person.constructor('tom')
console.log(person);
console.log(person2);
```

What's interesting is if we leave out the `new` keyword like in the following example:

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name
}

person = new Person('bob');
person2 = person.constructor('tom')
console.log(person);
console.log(person2);
```

It actually seems like the constructor is rerun and mutates the object with the new parameter. Is this what's happening?

Without the `new` keyword nothing is returned to `person2` at all. And `person`'s name property is now `'tom'`.

If the before is true, the constructor with out the `new` keyword mutates the original object, is there ever a use case for when one would want to call the constructor again on an object?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe if you are using the object as a singleton and want to change some value within it by way of the constructor.

Comment: why not just use an instance method in that case

Comment: Like I said, I was just guessing, I really don't have a concrete example. Maybe someone else will.

Comment: I suppose this should all start with the definition of "constructor". Then we discuss why we would want to use it for other than its intended purpose.

Comment: is that what the constructor does without the `new` keyword though?

Comment: I'd like to know your opinions on the latter half  @RandyCasburn

Comment: See my answer - didn't want to post that in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't use `new`, `Person` is just a regular function. Calling it will take an argument and set the `name` property on `this`. Called in this way `this` refers to the instance you just created. The function doesn't return anything, so it's essentially a setter.

You will see this kind of use of a constructor occasionally with inheritance patterns:

```js
function SuperClass(name) {
  this.name = name
}

function ChildClass(city, name) {
  this.city = city
  // use the superClass constructor to set properties:
  SuperClass.call(this, name)
}
// manipulate prototype 

let me = new ChildClass("Anchorage", "Mark")
console.log(me)
```

Taking advantage of this in other contexts is probably unnecessarily confusing when you can just make a dedicated setter function.

Answer (score 3):

If an ES5 constructor function is invoked without the `new` keyword (i.e. *called* instead of *constructed*), and it doesn't have a `return` statement, it will return `undefined`.

In addition, you are calling the constructor with `person` as the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) context of the function call via the [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) `person.constructor('tom')`, which is equivalent to [`person.constructor.call(person, 'tom')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), so it will overwrite the name of the first instance you initialized.

---

A related pattern that used to be somewhat common when ES5 was the latest specification was the use of self-correcting constructors by using an [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) check to conveniently avoid misusing the constructor. It would not have been caught in this case, but would be caught if you had invoked `Person('tom')` instead of `new Person('tom')`, which is a lot more common:

```js
function Person(name) {
  if (!(this instanceof Person)) return new Person(name);

  this.name = name;
}

console.log(new Person('bob'));
console.log(Person('tom'));
```

Comment: awesome, is there a use case for `.constructor` without the `new` keyword?

Comment: I would hardly call it a "usecase" so much as a "bad practice", but yes this behavior is well defined by the language specification.

Answer (score 1):

From MDN concerning the `new` operator:

> The new operator creates an instance of a user-defined object type or
>   of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor
>   function.The new keyword does the following 4 things
>
> 1. It creates a brand new object out of thin air.
> 2. It links this object to another object
> 3. the newly created object from Step 1 gets passed as the this context
> 4. if the function doesn't return it's own object, this is returned

If a constructor is called without the use of the new operator, it simply operates like any other Object method.

Comment: which in this case mutates the object, are there any uses cases for `.constructor` ?

Comment: What Andrew Kim said - no need to repeat.